# Google maps showing somewhere in France

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

On [console.cloud.google.com](http://console.cloud.google.com) I have enabled billing and restricted the API to my website.  (My website is using the kadence virtue wordpress theme).

When I open the contact form, it shows somewhere in France instead of Dublin, Ireland.  I believe this is a standard error.
[image: why france why]

If I do not include the website address in the unrestricted list nothing show on the website up which indicates the API calls are working.  Also, the calls are showing on the API request graph, (another good sign).

The APIs are in use:

[image]

Google Maps Platform API Checker looks ok:

> Maps Platform Report SUCCESS: Woohoo! This site is correctly using an
>   API key when loading the Maps JavaScript API v3.
>
> JS API Call: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIza*****1ZtY

Any ideas why it is still displaying the area in France and not Dublin Ireland?

Comment: What does your code look like that displays the map?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I am using the Kadence Virtue Wordpress Theme, edited to point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#geocoding-request-and-response-latitudelongitude-lookup) must be enabled.

> Convert addresses into geographic coordinates (geocoding), which you
>   can use to place markers or position the map. This API also allows you
>   to convert geographic coordinates into an address (reverse geocoding).

The calls were being executed but the addresses were obviously not being converted to coordinates.  3 - 4 hours of my life lost, hope this helps someone else.